# How can I calculate the ratio of a value in array to the sum of array in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array such as this:

```
array =[[1,2,3],
        [5,3,4],
        [6,7,2]]
```

and for each member I would like to calculate the ratio of them to the sum of the row.

Therefore, the result of my question in proposed sample is:

```
result = [[1/(1+2+3),2/(1+2+3),3/(1+2+3)],
          [5/(5+3+4),3/(5+3+4),4/(5+3+4)],
          [6/(6+7+2),7/(6+7+2),2/(6+7+2)]]
```

I write the following code but it does not work because two operators have different shape:

```
array/array.sum(array, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify `keepdim=True` while doing the sum, and then you have a 2d array as result while each row stands for the row sum:

```
array = np.array([[1,2,3],
        [5,3,4],
        [6,7,2.]])

array/array.sum(1, keepdims=True)
#array([[ 0.16666667,  0.33333333,  0.5       ],
#       [ 0.41666667,  0.25      ,  0.33333333],
#       [ 0.4       ,  0.46666667,  0.13333333]])
```