# calculates the ratio of entries in an array over the sum of the numbers in the array

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a method in numpy that calculates the ratio of entries in an array over the sum of the numbers in the array? For example:

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>datas=[1,2,3,3,100]
>>>np.frequencies(datas)
[1/109,2/109,3/109,3/109,100/109]
```

Comment: Are you asking given an array, find the ratio of entries which exceed the sum of the array? E.g given `[1,2,3]` find the ratio of values that exceed 6 (the sum)?

Comment: No I mean, it should return [1/6,2/6,3/6]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you're saying you can just do the following

```
import numpy as np
datas=np.asarray([1,2,3,3,100])  # Convert to a numpy array 
answer_you_want = datas / sum(datas)
```

Comment: it is an obvious duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45364832/how-can-i-calculate-the-ratio-of-a-value-in-array-to-the-sum-of-array-in-python